# Using JSON instead of JSONP with a YUI3 DataSource

Tags: json, jsonp, datasource, yui3

I'm populating a YUI DataTable via JSON, starting from the sample code [DataTable + DataSource.Get + JSON Data](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-dsget.html).  Despite its promising title, this sample uses JSONP, not straight JSON.  In my case, I'm querying with a relative URL, so I don't need (or want) JSONP.

My code defines a data source and schema like this:

```
var dataSource = new Y.DataSource.Get({ source: "myLocalUrl.json" });
dataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
    schema: { resultListLocator: "result.path.to.array", resultFields: ["key1", "key2"]}
});
```

Nowhere in here does it specify JSONP, but apparently that's the default behavior-- despite the security warnings in the JSONP documentation.  Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I've checked the API docs for Y.DataSource and Y.DataSource.Get, and neither is particularly enlightening.

Comment: The docs are brutal and rife with errors. Such beautiful code should have worthy docs.

Answer (score 2):

I had better luck with [DataSource.IO](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datasource/datasource-io.html)

```
var dataSource = new Y.DataSource.IO({ source: "myLocalUrl.json" });
dataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
    schema: { resultListLocator: "result.path.to.array", resultFields: ["key1", "key2"]}
});
```